# How do I remove blank lines from a text file and join the lines separated by the blank line?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file which some of the entries look like this:

```
"Hello, my name is

George. Its very nice to meet you"
```

and I would like to run an SED or AWK command that gives me the following result:

```
"Hello, my name is George. Its very nice to meet you"
```

I know I can remove blank lines with SED by running:

```
sed '/^\s*$/d'
```

That command only removes the blank line but it does not join the string as shown above.

Thanks

Comment: can you paste more content of your file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n";ORS=" "}1' file
```

The command is using two newlines (a blank line) as the input separator and a space as the *output record separator*.

`1` is an awk idiom. It will always evaluate to true which makes `awk` print every record.

---

Btw, if your blank lines may contain whitespace, change the command to:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n[[:space:]]*\n";ORS=" "}1' file
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It did work with a test file I created but it does not work on the file I need to fix. Perhaps there are some garbage characters in the supposedly empty lines? I do not see any.

Comment: Probably the file you are working on is from Windows?

Answer (score -1):

Go menu -> Edit -> Line operations - Choose "Remove Empty Lines" in Notepad ++

in one click all extra lines get removed :)